# Databinding on custom View boolean attribute not working

Tags: android, android-view, android-databinding

I have a custom view that has a `read` attribute, defined in xml like this:

```
<attr name="read" format="boolean" />
```

I get this attribute in the `init` method of the custom view:

```
read = getBoolean(R.styleable.CustomCardView_read, true)
```

This sets the following property of the view:

```
var read: Boolean = false
    set(value) {
        field = value
        card_read_stripe.visibility = if (value) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
    }
```

When I use this custom view I bind the `read` property like this:

```
app:read="@{!object.fresh}"
```

My problem is that I always get `true` from the styled attributes but never any value from the databinding side. The setter of `read` is only called once with the default value of the attrs.xml attribute. The custom view also has some string attributes that are bound via databinding and those are implemented in the exact same way and they work without a problem. What could be the cause here?

Comment: it is common problem after doing things with databinding, always first try to clean and reguild project

Answer (score 0):

The error seemed to be that the databinding compiler did not generate new code somehow. After cleaning and rebuilding the whole project it started working again.